# Save entity in table that has 2 Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I work with EF6. I have table with this structure :

```
Id | CompanyId | CourierId | DateOfCreation
```

`CompanyId` and `CourierId` can be null, because if one value exists another is null.

And these columns are foreign keys to the tables `Companies` and `Couriers`.

When I try to save some entity in this table, I get error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_SendedInvoices_Couriers". The conflict occurred in database "Courier", table "dbo.Couriers", column 'Id'.

If I understand correctly problem in that `CourierId` is null and it can't map to `Couriers` table.

But I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE :

So real entity looks like :

```
public partial class SendedInvoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SendingHistoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourierId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Courier Courier { get; set; }
    public virtual InvoicesSendingHistory InvoicesSendingHistory { get; set; }
}
```

This is how i init my entity.

```
private static SendedInvoice InitSendedInvoiceModel(InvoiceData data, int historyId, bool isFreelance)
        {
            var sendedInvoice = new SendedInvoice
                                {
                                    CompanyId = isFreelance ? 0 : data.CustomerId,
                                    SendingHistoryId = historyId,
                                    CourierId = isFreelance ? data.CustomerId : 0
                                };
            return sendedInvoice;
        }
```

and then save it.

```
 public bool AddInvoiceServiceRun(SendedInvoice data)
    {
        var courier = _context.Couriers.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == data.CourierId);
        var company = _context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == data.CompanyId);

        data.Company = company;
        data.Courier = courier;
        _context.SendedInvoices.Add(data);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is your table ready to accept null values inside these columns? Can you provide SQL script for table creation?

Comment: No, the error says you're trying to store a `CourierId` value into your table that doesn't exist in `Couriers`, thus violating the FK constraint. Can you **show us the code** that creates that entity and saves it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing your `CourierId` value to the numerical value of `0` here (if `isFreelance` is false):

```
private static SendedInvoice InitSendedInvoiceModel(InvoiceData data, int historyId, bool isFreelance)
{
    var sendedInvoice = new SendedInvoice
                            {
                                CompanyId = isFreelance ? 0 : data.CustomerId,
                                SendingHistoryId = historyId,
                                CourierId = isFreelance ? data.CustomerId : 0
                            };
    return sendedInvoice;
}
```

When saving this entity, this value `0` will be stored in your entity, and SQL Server will try to establish a FK relationship to `Couriers` with `Id = 0` - since you're storing that value. Does that `Courier` with `Id = 0` exist??

Most probably, you wanted to initialize your `CourierId` to `null` if `isFreelance` is false ...

```
private static SendedInvoice InitSendedInvoiceModel(InvoiceData data, int historyId, bool isFreelance)
{
    var sendedInvoice = new SendedInvoice
                            {
                                CompanyId = isFreelance ? null : data.CustomerId,
                                SendingHistoryId = historyId,
                                CourierId = isFreelance ? data.CustomerId : null
                            };
    return sendedInvoice;
}
```

**THEN** SQL Server will receive a `NULL` and store it as `CourierId` and not worry about checking the FK relationship ....

Side note: this code here is **totally superfluous**:

```
public bool AddInvoiceServiceRun(SendedInvoice data)
{
    var courier = _context.Couriers.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == data.CourierId);
    var company = _context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == data.CompanyId);

    data.Company = company;
    data.Courier = courier;
    _context.SendedInvoices.Add(data);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

You don't need to look up those `Courier` and `Company` instances - you've **already** set the foreign key values (`CourierId` and `CompanyId`) - just save your entity and the next time you load those, the referenced objects will be automagically also be set for you.